# Releasing resources in android

Tags: android, resources, media-player, release

My first post... you know...

I Created a class :

```
public class MyPanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder,
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
   private MediaPlayer shooting = new MediaPlayer();
   public Panel(Context context, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        super(context);
    shooting = MediaPlayer
                .create(ctx, Utils.getRawResIdFromName("gunshot"));
  }
  void  anotherMethod(){
    //...
    shooting.start();
  }
//....other stuff....
 }
```

Now the activity Class's onCreate method is simple:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ... some stuff
    final MyPanel panel = new MyPanel(this, newWidth, newHeight);
    }
... other methods
}
```

My question here is how to release the resources after the user exits the activity ? 
I am not sure how to release the instantiated object panel and all the objects created in it like MediaPlayer, Graphics....

Thanks

askanaan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `onDestroy()` nullify all your object variables, this will make them eligible for `System GC` to collect them. OR explicitly call `System.gc()`

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your `onDestroy()`.

But it is not necessary to do this, but a good prectice. As Android's GC is very intelligent.

I think you have iPhone dev background, that's why you are asking this question. :)